# Get value from query string

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

```
http://localhost:3000/hospital/public/service/create?5
```

I want to get this 5 in value of input of create page.

```
 <input type="number" name="patient_id" class="form-control" placeholder="ID" value="">
```

Comment: Perhaps you might be able to use `$key = Input::get('key');` and then use it inside value. See https://www.5balloons.info/how-to-get-url-parameters-into-controller-laravel/

Answer (score 0):

5 is hanging in the air, I think the url should be:

```
http://localhost:3000/hospital/public/service/create?patient_id=5
```

and then

```
<input type="number" name="patient_id" class="form-control" placeholder="ID" value="<?= Input::get('patient_id'); ?>">
```

or whatever the php-bplade syntac is. `<?= ?>` might not work

Comment: It doesn't get like that because patient_id is in service table in order to get patient id